# Word counter Program In Java

Tags: java

While creating a word counter in java through collecting user input from a scanner I've been running into the error of having my program display that there was one extra word entered when there is a space entered in after the final word in the char.  Is there a way to check the user input for a space and remove it before entering my word count loop?

Comment: Regex is always the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Right after...

```
String userinput = wordcounter.nextLine();
```

... add this line:

```
userinput = userinput.trim();
```

It should fix the problem, since the function `trim()` gets rid of any blank spaces at the beginning or ending of the string.

Comment: Thanks so much I was unaware of the trim function

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int word = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    Scanner wordcounter = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (wordcounter.hasNext()) {
        wordcounter.next();
        word++;
    }
    System.out.println("You hav entered " + word + " words.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moreover there are many functions in Java that you can use here to do this very easily like using string tokenizer, etc. But if you want to make changes in the above program, you could simply do a simple check statement before the main if condition that if the I == length-1, because this means that you are at the last character and there is nothing after this, for this case you could just continue or break. Hopefully I solved your query, do tell in case you need more clarification...

Answer (score 0):

One possible way: **use regex after you trim your input.**

---

```
String text = "I turned myself into a pickle Morty! :)";
String[] words = text.split("([\\W\\s]+)");
int count = 0;
for (String word: words) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("You have entered " + count + " words!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Write something");
    String x = in.nextLine();
    char y;
    char z;
    int n =1;
    boolean t = true;
    boolean f = false;
    boolean o = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<x.length();i++){
    y = x.charAt(i);
    if(t){
    if(' ' == y){n--;}
    else if(y != ' '){ t=false; f = true;}
    }
    if(' ' == y){n++;}
    if(o){
        z = x.charAt(i-1);
    if(' ' == y && ' '== z){n--;}
    }
    if (o){
    if(' ' == y && i == x.length()-1){n--;}
    }
    if(f){o = true;}

    }
    System.out.println(n);
```

This actually works lol